# MySQL 8 says root password is incorrect, but not on 5.7?

Tags: mysql

Just created an Ubuntu 20.04 box (MySQL 8.0), and after installing MySQL, logging in with root on the command line always says the password is incorrect even when it's correct.  I don't get this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 (MySQL 5.7).  Did something change between those versions?

Comment: mysql 8 doesn't support the old password , because it is insecure, you can change it during installation to legacy mode or define the user as using native password see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html if you want to do it for all user. but takle a look aroud for that matter

Comment: I've done msql_secure_installation.  This is on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 box vs a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 box.  I'm using a rather secure password that is about 40 characters long.   I've even tested it with a shorter password (on another fresh box) just to make sure I'm not somehow typoing, and literally no matter what password I use, MySQL 8 claims the password is wrong.  It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Include the exact error message in your question. Are you entering the password on the command line? or on a password prompt? What is your mysql client that you are using to connect?

Comment: It says ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't solve it, as root is simply cannot be logged in outside of `sudo mysql` for whatever reason on MySQL 8 on my box, but I got around that by creating a new user and using that instead.  Manually setting the login plugin didn't change anything either, it just won't allow non sudo login on root alone, and sudo login doesn't ask me for password.